# java printf format double with a string parameter

Tags: java, format, printf

In Java, I want to scan user for formatString and inputDouble as follows:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter formating string and double to format:");
String formatString = scan.next();
Double inputDouble = scan.nextDouble();
```

But for now, let's say I only have

```
String formatString = "%.2f";
Double inputDouble = 42.424242;
```

I would to use the System.out.printf(); to format the inputDouble based on the formatString. Something like:

```
System.out.printf("Formated double: '%s'", formatString, inputDouble);
```

so something in form:

```
System.out.printf("Formated double: 'magicGoesHere'", formatString, inputDouble);
```

So in this particular case, I would like to see output:

```
Formated double: 42.42
```

Is it possible somehow? thanks

Comment: `String.format(formatString, inputDouble)`, then use the resulting `String` in your `System.out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("Formated double: '%s'", String.format (formatString, inputDouble));
```

Comment: Alternatively: `System.out.printf(String.format("Formated double: '%s'", formatString), inputDouble)`.

Answer (score 1):

Split the call up into parts:

```
System.out.print("Formated double: '");
System.out.printf(formatString, inputDouble);
System.out.print("'");
```

Comment: nice trick, didn't think of it, but I really like it, Thanks :)